# We cannot use place holder shorcut in Playground file yet

Tags: shortcut, swift, xcode6

It looks like a kind of bug. 
I tried practicing swift-language on playground.
But place holder shortcut(ctrl+slash) cannot be used in playground yet.

Then I searched the solution to solve this problem. But failed. It is working very well in other swift files.

Anybody know why cannot or any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this functionality is not yet implemented/hooked up. Don't expect Playgrounds to be a fully working and/or stable feature at this point. They are a new feature in a pre-release version of Xcode. They are going to have problems.

A workaround for this is to just press tab. That will jump to the next placeholder.

Hope this helps!